# TypeError: inverse is not a function (in handlebars helper)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I need a way to compare values in handlebars and found this helper on the web:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('compare', function(lvalue, rvalue, options) {

    if (arguments.length < 3)
        throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' needs 2 parameters");

    var operator = options.hash.operator || "==";

    var operators = {
        '==':       function(l,r) { return l == r; },
        '===':      function(l,r) { return l === r; },
        '!=':       function(l,r) { return l != r; },
        '<':        function(l,r) { return l < r; },
        '>':        function(l,r) { return l > r; },
        '<=':       function(l,r) { return l <= r; },
        '>=':       function(l,r) { return l >= r; },
        'typeof':   function(l,r) { return typeof l == r; }
    }

    if (!operators[operator])
        throw new Error("Handlerbars Helper 'compare' doesn't know the operator "+operator);

    var result = operators[operator](lvalue,rvalue);

    if( result ) {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
```

This is how I use it:

```
{{#each numbers as |nr|}}
         {{#compare nr stars operator="<=" }}

             <span{{action "rate" }}  class="rating{{nr}} glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>

         {{/compare}}


       {{/each}}
});
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: options.inverse is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the `else` section for *compare* block helper.

> Handlebars provides the block for the else fragment as options.inverse. You do not need to check for the existence of the else fragment: Handlebars will detect it automatically.

Source: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#conditionals

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to go with principle of least surprise in the helper:

```js
if (typeof options.inverse == function)
  return options.inverse(this);
else
  return null;
```

Which isn't bad practice for any Handlebars helper; don't try to render an inverse if the template writer didn't provide one.